# Testing PCI Card

Tags: pci

I have two questions I will try to be detailed as I can here.  I have a PCI Wifi card I want to know if it works or not.  I do NOT have a computer in which to test this on. The model #F5D7000 is a Belkin card (yep it's old).

The PCI slots are the Universal 3.3v/5v 32 bit CONVENTIONAL type.  I want to use a test light but I do not know what pins can be used to test.

I have searched Google for this on how to test but to no avail (however with answers posted here a Google search will turn up results). What pins can I use to test this device?  I THINK it is dead because I removed it and got a Linksys 
one but it has been 12 years ago.

I don't want to waste this part since I paid for it.

PS ONE MORE THING as Uncle said, how and what can I use to PULL radio waves toward me of any type?  Enhance reception?  Merci.

Comment: "what can I use to PULL radio waves toward me" - a black hole.

Comment: Ideally you should split this into two separate questions. This site is not geared towards conversational-style discourse, its intended use is for single-topic questions and responses. Your question about directional radio wave propagation is very much unrelated to your question about PCI go/no-go testing so they don't belong together.

Answer (score 1):

Without a computer to talk to it, I suspect you're out of luck. Most of the devices from this time period needed a device driver to expose the functions of the card, as such without something to talk to it, and interface via the driver, there is no means to know if it functions

I'm going to make some assumptions on the second part. To enhance reception you use a more directional antenna, the normal little stick antennas are "omni-directional" so they take in a smaller signal, but it doesn't really matter which direction you are vs the router,

But if you know where it is and that doesn't change much, you can use higher gain antennas that reduce how wide an area the router can be in because its focused in on a smaller area, but that means it sees a stronger signal.